# ssmtp: 550 invalid DNS MX or A/AAAA resource record

Tags: email, centos, smtp, centos7, ssmtp

I am trying to send a mail from centos machine, but I came to a problem. I have installed "mail" and ssmtp inside my linux machine and I got this response when I try to send a mail.

> ssmtp: 550 invalid DNS MX or A/AAAA resource record
>
> FromLineOverride=YES
> mailhub=smtp.1und1.de:587
> UseSTARTTLS=YES

Of course, with the correct password and user.
I have tried already couple of users and everybody are returning the same.
I have tried even with my own user and the password that I have, but it won't work.
If you have any other approaches to this problem let me know also.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Is your SMTP server running on a machine with a dynamic ip address? What is the domain of your server and doesn't it have a proper DNS record?

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be the FROM address for the SMTP envelope. Some SMTP servers will ignore an invalid value like Gmail for example (that's why it worked for me with Gmail) but if you're using 1und1 SMTP-Server you have to override the domain if it's not the same as the mail domain (e.g. if you're on a local test server).
You can override the domain in the `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf`:

Assuming your email is: my@yourdomain.de

```
rewriteDomain=yourdomain.de
```

Comment: Hey Sepultura, thanks for help. 
I know that I could override the ssmtp.conf. i have done that and now I have new error message. 

*** Error in `ssmtp': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000001c3a693 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7ada4)[0x7f0b00b8fda4]
ssmtp[0x403608]
ssmtp[0x40464c]
ssmtp[0x4020e9]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f0b00b36b35]
ssmtp[0x402131]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00409000 r-xp 00000000 09:02 6556005                            /usr/sbin/ssmtp